# Extracting attributes of points within overlapping polygons in ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, point-in-polygon

I have a set of overlapping polygons and a line of points. A single points can fall within any number of polygons, and I need to determine the attribute values of points that fall within each polygon.

My outlined workflow was:

1. Select each polygon individually using [SelectLayerByAttribute_management](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/data-management/select-layer-by-attribute.htm)
2. Select the points which fall within that selected polygon using [SelectLayerByLocation_management](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/select-layer-by-location.htm)
3. Iterate through the selected points and extract their attribute values using SearchCursor

The issue I'm running into is that according to [this post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/67002/select-by-atribute-using-python-script-on-shp-file-getting-error-000840-the-val) the polygons for step 1 have to be a "layer" rather than a feature class or shapefile. However for step 2, the polygons cannot be "layers" and have to be a feature class or shapefile.

I was relying on the selection of the polygon features in step 1 and 2 to to be the same. This works inside of ArcMap using the Python console, but I am unable to produce more than the first line.

Comment: Both Select commands (#1 and #2) require a Layer as input.

Comment: Use [MakeFeatureLayer](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/data-management/make-feature-layer.htm) to create a layer from a shapefile or GDB feature class

Comment: @Bjorn That's what I was doing. For some reason it wouldn't accept the layer as the third argument in the SelectLayerByLocation. I got it to work by saving the result of MakeFeatureLayer into a variable and then referencing that. The string name of the layer wouldn't work.

Comment: For questions that involve code please always include a code snippet that illustrates what you have tried and where you are stuck, and any error message that results.