# arcpy.SelectLayerByLocation_management gives ERROR 000368?

Tags: arcpy, select-by-location, error-000368

I have 2 shape files. One is a polygon while other is polyline. I need to select all the polylines that are completely inside the polygon. However this doesnot seem to work in any way.

```
NewLinks = "NewLinks.shp"
Buffer = "Buffer.shp"
Buffer1 = "Buffer1.shp"
arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(Buffer, Buffer1) 
arcpy.SelectLayerByLocation_management(NewLinks, "COMPLETELY_WITHIN", Buffer1, "", "NEW_SELECTION", "NOT_INVERT")
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.5\ArcPy\arcpy\management.py", line 7860, in SelectLayerByLocation
raise e
arcgisscripting.ExecuteError: Failed to execute. Parameters are not valid.
ERROR 000368: Invalid input data.
Failed to execute (SelectLayerByLocation).
```

Comment: Does this answer help?  https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/67017/43

Comment: @RichardMorgan I added that and tried, it shows the same error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`SelectLayerByLocation_management` input must be a feature layer, so make one from the shp file first, then pass that into the method.

```
NewLinks = "NewLinks.shp"
Buffer = "Buffer.shp"
arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(NewLinks, 'newlinks_lyr') 
arcpy.SelectLayerByLocation_management('newlinks_lyr', "COMPLETELY_WITHIN", Buffer, "", "NEW_SELECTION", "NOT_INVERT")
```

Also, I tend to be very explicit with paths to any files; your code may now complain it can't find those .shp files.